# runef command not found

Tags: python, pyomo

Hi I installed pysp package using pip. and according to documents now I should be able to run runef command in terminal. but it gives error " command not found "
I also installed pyomo and it is working fine.
my os is ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**coopr.pysp**  https://pypi.org/project/coopr.pysp/

`bin/runef` is provided by the package coopr.pysp

> "This Python package defines stochastic programming extensions for the
> Pyomo modeling language"

`pip install coopr.pysp`

(Plain "pysp" is *Python-Support-Package*  https://pypi.org/search/?q=pysp )